# Zoom in and out buttons on World Map using D3

Tags: javascript, button, d3.js, zooming

I need to add the zoom in and out button on the world map using D3, but I am unable to implement it. Currently my code is featured on this link:
https://digitalxlabs.com/animated-banners/world-map-template12.php

```
Username: DXLdemo

Password: View@098#
```

I've tried using the Mike Bostock's example for adding the Zoom button 3, but I am unable to implement it. Can someone please look into this and let me know this can be done.

Comment: the link is asking for a username and password to access

Comment: please use the same username and password as provided above in the question:
Username: DXLdemo        Password:  View@098#

Comment: damn, sorry, obvious now :) At what position do you want the button to zoom in and out from, presuming the center?

Comment: Hi Stacy,

I want them in the top right corner of the page with fixed position same as the key I have on the bottom. 
I need to deliver this functionality today, please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Stacey burns,

Just wanted to confirm if this can be implemented or not, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was more talking about the zoom logic. For sure you can add a couple of buttons. All you need to do is create the elements and add a click event to it that calls the zoom. There are a couple of examples of how to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488972/d3js-use-view-port-center-for-zooming-focal-point

Comment: Silly question maybe. Isn't mouse wheel zoom more practical and its yet implemented?

Comment: Not a silly question @Klaujesi. We're targeting all user who works on laptop and adding a zoom-in and out button is standard way on the map. If you haven't seen it yet please try viewing the google map for better clarification. Hope this might clear your doubt on the silly fact of not adding any zoom-in and out button.