# d3.js: Zoom on click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was trying to get same behavior [Wil Linssen's implementation](http://bl.ocks.org/linssen/7352810)
but on d3.js version 4.
I am quite confused with zoom api in version 4.

The changes that I made in the original implementation is:
`zoom.translate()` replaced with 
   `d3.zoomTransform(selection.node())` and appropriate points added instead:

```
svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + t.x + "," + t.y + ")" +
    "scale(" + t.k + ")"
);
```

This one:

```
zoom
  .scale(iScale(t))
  .translate(iTranslate(t));
```

replaced to

```
var foo = iTranslate(t);
zoom.
  translateBy(selection, foo[0], foo[1]);
zoom
  .scaleBy(selection, iScale(t));
```

But it's still has a problem, looks like with scale, zoom out...

Example: [Example on d3.v4 - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbabenko/8t0rv5yn/3/)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching the most easiest way to use d3 v4 api that provides interpolation etc out of box. In original question zoom implemented from scratch, that doesn't make sense in version 4. Solution is similar to @Nixie answers and has few lines of code.

This version includes pan as well, if you do not need, remove `svg.call(zoom);`

Final example: [Zoom D3 v4 - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbabenko/jcsqqu6j/9/)

One interesting note:
The function:

```
function transition() {
  svg.transition()
      .delay(100)
      .duration(700)
      .call(zoom.scaleTo, zoomLevel);
      //.on("end", function() { canvas.call(transition); });
}
```

`call(zoom.ScaleTo, zoomLevel)` - will zoom to the center of page. But if you need the center of an image, use this one: `call(zoom.transform, transform);`

Where `transform` is a function that sets center of your image. For example of such function:

```
function transform() {
  return d3.zoomIdentity
      .translate(width / 2.75, height / 2.75)
      .scale(zoomLevel)
      .translate(-width/2.75, -height/2.75);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code does not resolve all the problems, but could be a starting point. In D3 v4 you can transition zoom in one line of code (see also https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_transform)

```
function interpolateZoom (translate, scale) {
    return selection.transition().duration(350)
              .call(zoom.transform, 
                    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale))
}
```

Modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/2yx1cLrq/. Also, you need to replace `selection` with `selection.node()` in all calls to `d3.zoomTransform`

Comment: To make it even shorter I guess you can skip the `var self = this;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Angular for this, and it's in my opinion the simplest and cleanest so far. I already had scroll to zoom behavior, adding mouse clicks was easy. Please note I import my d3 functions using ES6 modules.
Example:

```
import { event as d3event, zoom, scaleExtent, selectAll, transition, duration } from 'd3';
```

My existing zoom (mouse scroll)

```
this.zoom = zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on('zoom', this.zoomed.bind(this));

// this.chart is my map chart svg created by d3
this.chart.call(this.zoom)

zoomed() {
// this.g is a <g> element appended to the chart that contains all countries in my case.
    this.g
      .selectAll('path') // To prevent stroke width from scaling
      .attr('transform', d3event.transform);
  }
```

What I added to get zoom buttons:

```
<!-- My markup -->
<button (click)="zoomClick(1.5)">Zoom in</button>
<button (click)="zoomClick(0.5)">Zoom out</button>
```

```js
zoomClick(level): void {
  this.chart.transition().duration(200).call(this.zoom.scaleBy, level);
}
```